# DXA Publish Settings: Possible to add multimedia Components and linked Components?

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-1.7

So for DXA there is the `Publish Settings` Page located in the `_System` folder of each Publication.

As far as I understood we can currently only add strings and read them either with `${localization.getConfiguration('core.showingItemsText')}` or with `${markup.resource("core.showingItemsText")}` based on the config type.

My question is: Can I also add regular Components and multimedia Components to the configuration Page and make them accessible on every Page?

For example we are using the same DXA webapp for about 900 Publications and each one uses their own interchangable design elements that needs to be rendered on multiple different sections on each request.

For example the header logo, which is currently a Component on our Header include Page, also needs to appear in each ajax popup and we only want to include it once per Publication. So my intention is to remove the Header Component from my include Page and add it to the configuration so I can read it on multiple sections on my Page.

I did try to add the logo into the configuration Component but it only results in a `json` located in `/BinaryData`, no luck in rendering the image yet.

Comment: I get where you want to go to, but I'm missing the actual question. Other than me saying, the answer is currently not. If you would **edit** your question and explain how you want to change the configuration to contain content, then the answers can address that. Mind you I don't think adding it in the configuration is a correct approach, I'd look into smaller regions (like a logo region for example) and reusing them (but each will have their pros and cons of course).

Comment: Re-using elements should be easy without needing to use DXA's Publish Settings. Could you clarify "read (the Logo) on multiple sections on my Page?" Is the _reading_ done by Component link or CSS class name and is this done by a developer or end-user? Knowing how the site should differ between Publications in terms of markup, text, or images can also help.